# SSH into vagrant with X server set up

Tags: windows, ssh, vagrant, putty, xming

I am running into problems with setting up X11 forwarding on vagrant VM.

I am running Xming for X server and PuTTY as my SSH client.

This is what I get when I run `vagrant ssh-config`:

```
Host default
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2200
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile C:/Users/MyName/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
  ForwardAgent yes
  ForwardX11 yes
```

My PuTTY has X11 forwarding enabled and X display location set to `0.0`.

When I do `echo $DISPLAY` I get no response.

I am unsure as to what I configured wrongly. I followed the [following advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885108/ssh-to-vagrant-box-in-windows) in setting up my PuTTY client. If there is an easier way to set up VM with X11 forwarding, please, let me know.

For reference these are contents of my `Vagrantfile`.

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.ssh.forward_agent = true
  config.ssh.forward_x11 = true

end
```

Comment: This has been resolved by using Cygwin as X server by following this [advice](http://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/setup.html).

Comment: Could you please add it as an answer below and accept it? Comments are not the best place for correct answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install Cygwin with the following packages to resolve the problem as specified in this [website](http://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/setup.html):

- xorg-server
- xinit
- xorg-docs (for documentation)
- openssh (in case this wasn't installed previously)

Then load up the window using `startxwin` from the cygwin terminal.

A note that I discovered later is that it is better to ssh into vagrant using the following command:

`vagrant -Y ssh`

Than:

`vagrant -X ssh`

The latter is performed in untrusted mode as in this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/407218/why-does-ssh-x-forwarding-timeout-after-a-while) and times out after a while.

Answer (score 9):

I had a very similar issue, but in my case it was an issue with the Vagrant VM. Here are some things to check:

- `X11Forwarding` needs to be set to `yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
- Enable verbose logging for ssh (`vagrant ssh -- -vvv -X` in Linux, Putty also seems to have a `-v` command line flag) and look for interesting messages.

With my Vagrant VM the latter revealed the following message:

```
debug1: Remote: No xauth program; cannot forward with spoofing
```

After installing a package that provides `xauth` (`xorg-xauth`, `xorg-x11-xauth` or similar), `vagrant ssh -- -X` worked fine.

Comment: The setting in `sshd_config` is the secret sauce most descriptions of this fail to mention!

Answer (score 1):

Use "startxwin" to run the cygwin X server. Use putty or the cygwin ssh client to ssh to your guest virtual machine.

If using cygwin ssh, do "export DISPLAY=:0" before running ssh (ie "vagrant ssh -- -vvv -X").

For putty: Run "startxwin -- -listen tcp", enable ssh-X11 forwarding in the putty connection config, set "X display location" to "localhost:0" and set the correct path of the .Xauthority file (browse, it is probably in your home directory; startxwin output will tell you where).

Perhaps do not use msys2 ssh (the vagrant default installed environment is msys2 but vagrant also works fine under cygwin) with the cygwin X server. (see details for more info about why)

Details:

If you get "connect /tmp/.X11-unix/X0: No such file or directory" (under ssh verbose mode) or putty error "PuTTY X11 proxy: unable to connect to forwarded X server: Network error: Connection refused", try using tcp sockets rather than the default unix domain sockets.

When you run your Cygwin X server, go "X -listen tcp -multiwindow" (multiwindow is optional - it opens new windows for each app).

If using openssh "ssh" from the command-line: Before going "vagrant ssh -- -vvv -X", go "export DISPLAY=localhost:0" (not ":0" but "localhost:0" so it uses tcp). I am running git bash which uses msys2 which seems to not communicate properly with my cygwin X server over emulated unix domain sockets. But if I use "vagrant ssh -- -X" under my cygwin prompt (with DISPLAY=:0 for unix domain sockets), it works.

Great info source: http://dustwell.com/how-x-over-ssh-really-works.html

Also, you can add "config.ssh.forward_x11 = true" to your Vagrantfile. I think this sets X11Forwarding in /etc/ssh/sshd_config when the guest virtual machine is set up or "vagrant reload" is run. - https://coderwall.com/p/ozhfva/run-graphical-programs-within-vagrantboxes

Update: It is not recommended to run X without xauth security (as shown above). It is not secure. For example, other computers on the same LAN can connect to your x-server via tcp and sniff your keypresses using xkeys. Use "startxwin" instead of running X directly so it uses the "-auth" option of XWin. This makes it difficult for me to get my msys2 ssh to redirect X to my cygwin X server. The ssh log while connecting says it cannot find the xauth command - that is because it is not present in my msys2 environment. Cygwin ssh X-redirection still works fine. Putty works fine as long as you set the .Xauthority file path (it is probably right in your home directory) in the putty session config.

I discovered the tcp/unix-domain socket problem/solution is actually in the cygwin faq (this faq is quite helpful and has a lot of info):

6.7. X sessions forwarded by PuTTY can't connect. Non-cygwin local X clients can't connect.

The X server now uses -nolisten tcp by default, which increases the security of the X server by not opening a TCP/IP socket, only a local (UNIX domain) socket. Non-cygwin applications cannot connect to that socket.

https://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html