# Vagrant box: can't login with password from VirtualBox GUI

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I am learning to use Vagrant, and I tried to boot a Vagrant machine (an ubuntu/trusty64 built in the recommended way "vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64; vagrant up") from inside the VirtualBox GUI (double clicking the icon of the Vagrant machine). But I cannot login: no username, no password.

Do I need to add a specific provision, or there is another easier way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

**UPDATE after clarification of question**

You should be able to login as

```
user: vagrant
password: vagrant
```

This is a convention described in the [base box creation documentation](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/boxes/base.html):

> Also, even though Vagrant uses key-based authentication by default, it
>   is a general convention to set the password for the "vagrant" user to
>   "vagrant". This lets people login as that user manually if they need
>   to.

If you have a box where the password for the vagrant user is not set (or you just don't know it) you can do the following:

```
me@somebox$ vagrant ssh
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ sudo passwd vagrant 
Enter new UNIX password: <type invisible new password here>
Retype new UNIX password: <re-type invisible new password here>
passwd: password updated successfully
```

Now you can login e.g. through the VirtualBox GUI.

**Original answer** (basically explaining that you should not have to do the above)

The basic idea is, that you do not have to use the Virtual machine providers tools for anything to work with vagrant. So as soon as you think you have to use the VirtualBox GUI you are doing something wrong.

Just try in terminal (or in cmd.exe if you are on windows):

```
me@somebox$ vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64
me@somebox$ vagrant up
me@somebox$ vagrant ssh
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$
```

If everything works you should be on the command line inside your new machine logged in as the user vagrant.

Comment: Yes, of course, this is the normal way to get into the VM. But what if i'd decide to boot it outside Vagrant. It's not wrong, it's just another option. Do I really need to implement a provisioning that adds a new user?

Comment: "Just try in terminal (or in cmd.exe if you are on windows):"... `me@somebox$ vagrant ssh` - not in Windows cmd, you have to use Putty, [see this guide](http://tech.osteel.me/posts/2015/01/25/how-to-use-vagrant-on-windows.html#putty)

Comment: @ajmedway According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13482763/2626627) you just have to make sure that `ssh.exe` is in your PATH.

Comment: The most helpful statement in this answer for me was: 'as you think you have to use the VirtualBox GUI you are doing something wrong'. I was able to do everything from the command line that I wanted.

Comment: @FCo unless you want to test on an ubuntu gui client against a bunch other vagrant boxes you have networked together? Am I doing something wrong (as that^ is my case)?

Comment: @FCo Actually that's the _least_ helpful comment. For all future time, anyone who needs both SSH _and_ a GUI login to a vagrant-created VM, is going to search on the problem and run smack into this denial of their use case.