# Vagrant/VirtualBox not connecting ("Connection refused. Retrying...")

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrant-windows

I'm using Vagrant 1.7.2 and VirtualBox 4.3.28 (basically the latest builds as of the date) on Windows 8. I'm having trouble ssh-ing into the VM via `vagrant up`.

Here is the message I get:

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'hashicorp/precise32' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
```

I have a feeling this has something to do with my private key, but I have no idea how to solve it.

Here is my Vagrant file, which is basically the default one:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
    config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
end
```

Comment: Usually vagrant uses a custom key, which is stored in `$HOME/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key` (on Linux).. I'm not sure where it is stored on Windows, but I expect it also being located in the home folder. Can you search for that file?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9924122/171318

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSH to Vagrant box in Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885108/ssh-to-vagrant-box-in-windows)

Comment: Share your Vagrantfile

Comment: Might be related: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/4470

Comment: Maybe try using putty on 127.0.0.1:2222 ...

Comment: @hek2mgl I tried that following these instructions, but the same error comes up. https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV/wiki/Connect-to-Your-Vagrant-Virtual-Machine-with-PuTTY

Comment: Did you reboot the machine after installing VirtualBox?

Comment: @Alik It's the default Vagrantfile (as mentioned above)

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I've had VirtualBox for a while, but yes I reinstalled it/rebooted my machine after running into said problem.

Comment: There is a checklist for this problem: https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV/issues/375 look for this post: dezinerdudes commented on 3 Jul 2014

Comment: @SeanSaito could you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly unrelated but have you installing the VM VirtualBox Extension Pack for your particular version of virtualbox? https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads