# connecting to a docker container as a workspace

Tags: docker, workspace, mobaxterm

I currently use a vagrant box as my workspace for devops/cloud development.

[vagrant ssh not working in MobaXterm on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33879568/vagrant-ssh-not-working-in-mobaxterm-on-windows)

I saw this command for vagrant:
command /drives/c/HashiCorp/Vagrant/bin/vagrant ssh-config > vagrant-ssh-config && ssh -A -F vagrant-ssh-config default

in the advanced tab of the setting.

I am wanting to use mobaxterm to connect docker container to lighten up the start and requirements for my workspace. How would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

To be able to start a shell via MobaXterm on Windows:

1. Create a new shell from MobaXterm clicking "+" tab
   [image: Create a shell]
2. Go to your docker install directory:

`cd "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin"`

or with:

`cd /drives/c/Program Files/Docker/Docker/Resources/bin`

3. Execute docker exec command with `-i`nteractive option only:

`./docker.exe exec -i your_docker_container /bin/bash`

you are now in your docker container's bash environment, you can type `ls` for example:

[image: Docker exec command with ls example]

If you need to connect to a remote docker instance, adapt docker command to include remote host (`-H`)

*Tested with Windows 10, MobaXterm v10.9, docker v18.09.2.*

Note: after testing it during some time MobaXterm does not provide a good support to docker interactive console (bash support). Better use a cmd shell, powershell or similar.

Comment: Thank you for the good explanation. Is there an option to list the files in the sidebar e.g. https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSb9R.png ?

Answer (score 0):

@BlouBlou, thanks a lot for your answer
Just adding an information that was usefull for me.
When I tried to use:
"./docker.exe exec -i your_docker_container /bin/bash"
I connected to the terminal, but with blank screen.
Tried with "-it" and I've received the message below:
"the input device is not a TTY.  If you are using mintty, try prefixing the command with 'winpty'"

[I've found a simple solution in another another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48623005/docker-error-the-input-device-is-not-a-tty-if-you-are-using-mintty-try-prefi/49965690) that worked for me, and maybe for other users..
Just add winpty before docker.exe

cd "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin"; winpty ./docker.exe exec  -ti yourcontainer /bin/bash

worked 100%, so far.

Regards.
Delocco