# Error in Docker: bad address to executables

Tags: docker

I'm trying to something with Docker.

Steps I'm doing:
- Launch Docker Quickstart Terminal
- run docker run hello-world

Then I get error like:
bash: /c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox/docker: Bad address

I have to say that I was able to run hello-world image, but now I'm not. I don't know what happend.

I don't know if it matters however I had some problems at instalation step.
Since I have git installed in non standard location. However it seems git bash.exe working correctly for Docker.

My environment:

- Windows 10
- Git 2.5.0 (installed before Docker)
- Docker Toolbox 1.9.1a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue with `bash: /c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox/docker: Bad address`

I thought the problems is "bash doesn't support docker.exe".

SO  I fix this problem by use `powershell` ,not the bash.
and if you use powershell maybe face this

```
An error occurred trying to connect: Get http://localhost:2375/v1.21/containers/json: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2375: ConnectExenter code here
 tcp: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

You can export variable  from bash use `export` and import to powershell by this below

```
$env:DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"
$env:DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"
$env:DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
$env:DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALL_PATH="C:\\Program Files\\Docker Toolbox"
$env:DOCKER_CERT_PATH="C:\\Users\\kk580\\.docker\\machine\\machines\\default"
```

that's all

ps:I found this problem fixed by update git from 2.5.0 to 2.6.3.

Comment: Updating git to 2.6.4 resolved my problem. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what the issue is, [report it to the project on github](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues). I find the docker mac and windows tools a bit flakey from time to time as they are still maturing. If you don't mind seeing what's underneath, you can try running `docker-machine` directly or set up your own host pretty quickly with [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/).

#### Docker Machine

Run a command or bash prompt to see what machines you have.

```
docker-machine ls
```

Create a machine if you don't have one listed

```
docker-machine create -d "virtualbox" default-docker
```

Then connect to the listed machine (or `default-docker`)

```
docker-machine ssh default-docker
```

#### Vagrant

If that doesn't work you can always use vagrant to manage VM's

- [Install VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) (Which you probably have already if you installed the toolbox)
- [Reinstall Git](http://git-scm.com/downloads), make sure you select the option for adding *ALL* the tools to your system PATH (for `vagrant ssh`)
- [Install Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html)

Run a command or bash prompt

```
mkdir docker
cd docker
vagrant init debian/jessie64
vagrant up --provider virtualbox
```

Then to connect to your docker host you can run (from the same `docker` directory you created above)

```
vagrant ssh
```

Now your on the docker host, Install the latest docker the first time

```
curl https://get.docker.com/ | sudo sh
```

#### Docker

Now you have either a vagrant or docker-machine host up, you can docker away after that.

```
sudo docker run -ti busybox bash
```

You could also use [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) to connect to vagrant machines instead of installing git/ssh and running `vagrant ssh`. It provides a nicer shell experience [but it requires some manual setup of the ssh connections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9924122/1318694).