# Vagrant unable to communicate with virtual machine

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I am on windows 10. I have installed oracle virtual box. When I try to use the command 'vagrant up' in command prompt, I am getting time out error after 15 minutes. This is what I get in the command prompt.

```
Bringing machine 'sparkvm' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> sparkvm: Checking if box 'sparkmooc/base2' is up to date..
==> sparkvm: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> sparkvm: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> sparkvm: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    sparkvm: Adapter 1: nat
==> sparkvm: Forwarding ports...
    sparkvm: 8001 (guest) => 8001 (host) (adapter 1)
    sparkvm: 4040 (guest) => 4040 (host) (adapter 1)
    sparkvm: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> sparkvm: Booting VM...
==> sparkvm: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    sparkvm: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    sparkvm: SSH username: vagrant
    sparkvm: SSH auth method: private key
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the eror(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly 
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common 
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

I am using Virtual box version 5.0.14r105127 and my vagrant version is 1.8.1 and my vagrant file looks like this:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

ipythonPort = 8001                 # Ipython port to forward (also set in      IPython notebook config)

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.ssh.insert_key = true
  config.vm.define "sparkvm" do |master|
    master.vm.box = "sparkmooc/base2"
    master.vm.box_download_insecure = true
    master.vm.boot_timeout = 900
    master.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: ipythonPort, guest:     ipythonPort, auto_correct: true   # IPython port (set in notebook config)
    master.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 4040, guest: 4040,     auto_correct: true                 # Spark UI (Driver)
    master.vm.hostname = "sparkvm"
    master.vm.usable_port_range = 4040..4090

    master.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
      v.name = master.vm.hostname.to_s
    end
  end
end
```

Can someone please tell me what went wrong here?

Comment: Is the machine up in Virtualbox?

Comment: yes. the machine is up and running.

Comment: @jsfan when i try to open localhost:2222 in chrome, i get the message 'This webpage is not available

ERR_CONNECTION_RESET'

Comment: @jsfan when i tried, ie, i got this message 'we can't reach this page.

Try this
•Make sure you’ve got the right URL: http://localhost:2222'

Comment: @jsfan yes I can see all the three ports 2222, 4040, 8001 in the virtualbox

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885108/ssh-to-vagrant-box-in-windows). You might have no ssh client on your machine.