# Homestead on windows 10 hangs on default: SSH auth method: private key

Tags: windows, vagrant, homestead

```
Net::SSH::ConnectionTimeout>
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "a1035534-3544-40d1-a701-92e34436606b", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "a1035534-3544-40d1-a701-92e34436606b", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
 INFO ssh: Attempting SSH connection...
 INFO ssh: Attempting to connect to SSH...
 INFO ssh:   - Host: 127.0.0.1
 INFO ssh:   - Port: 2222
 INFO ssh:   - Username: vagrant
 INFO ssh:   - Password? false
 INFO ssh:   - Key Path: ["C:/Users/myuser/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key"]
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "a1035534-3544-40d1-a701-92e34436606b", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "a1035534-3544-40d1-a701-92e34436606b", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "a1035534-3544-40d1-a701-92e34436606b", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "a1035534-3544-40d1-a701-92e34436606b", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "a1035534-3544-40d1-a701-92e34436606b", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "a1035534-3544-40d1-a701-92e34436606b", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "a1035534-3544-40d1-a701-92e34436606b", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "a1035534-3544-40d1-a701-92e34436606b", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "a1035534-3544-40d1-a701-92e34436606b", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "a1035534-3544-40d1-a701-92e34436606b", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "a1035534-3544-40d1-a701-92e34436606b", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "a1035534-3544-40d1-a701-92e34436606b", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxManage.exe", "showvminfo", "a1035534-3544-40d1-a701-92e34436606b", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
 INFO ssh: SSH not ready: #<Vagrant::Errors::NetSSHException: An error occurred in the underlying SSH library that Vagrant uses.
The error message is shown below. In many cases, errors from this
library are caused by ssh-agent issues. Try disabling your SSH
agent or removing some keys and try again.

If the problem persists, please report a bug to the net-ssh project.
```

I tried all available solutions, nothing seems to work. The actual virtual machine starts, I can even log into it from virtual box.

Virtual Box versino: 5.1.6
Vagrant version: 1.8.6
OS: windows 10

Vagrant up just hangs and times out after displaying SSH auth method: private key. I've pasted the log. Any ideas?

Comment: did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885108/ssh-to-vagrant-box-in-windows/9924122#9924122

Comment: yeah, nothing to do with my problem, I'm 100% stuck

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if this solves your problem but you can try to ssh into your VM with the password `vagrant` instead of your private key.